# ObjectMapper exception using gRPC

Tags: json, jackson, grpc-java

I'm using gRPC (http://www.grpc.io) and I have a request from the client to the server. I wish to use `ObjectMapper mapper` or Jackson in order to create a Json String.

For exameple

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();       

try {
    NFFGSrpcreq1=NFFGSrpc.newBuilder().addNffg(request).build();

    // Convert object to JSON string
    String jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(req1);
    System.out.println(jsonInString);
} catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (JsonMappingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But during the execution I have a exception comes launch.

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 1):

How important is it to use Jackson?

If this is important, then I will advise you to create a class for an intermediate object that you will create from `NFFGSrpc req1` and then serialize it to JSON.

Otherwise you could use [Protocol Buffers [Util]](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java-util)  which provides `JsonFormat.Printer` class for converting protobuf messages to JSON format, e.g.:

```
JsonFormat.Printer printer = JsonFormat.printer();
NFFGSrpc req1 = NFFGSrpc.newBuilder().addNffg(request).build();
String jsonInString = printer.print(req);
```